# Adding a Property to a Deep Nested Object

Tags: entity-framework-core

Going to try and keep this post simple without posting every little class structure.

Here is the rough hierarchy of things:

- User is the account logged in to the application.
- A User has a list of Rooms.
- A Room has a list of Boxes.
- A Box has a list of Items.

Items can appear in multiple Boxes and the Item class is just properties of the Item with no tie back to what Box / Room / User it is associated to.

This sort of thing works fine for retrieving the data for the User.

```cs
_context.UserRooms
   .Include(b=> b.Boxes)
   .ThenInclude(i=> i.Items)
.Where (ur => ur.UserId == currentUserId);
```

The ask is to allow the user to attach a `Note` to an `Item`, such that no matter what Box that Item would appear in, it may (or may not) have a note that the User put there.

This is where I get confused where and how to add this Note.  There should only be one Note per User per Item.

I thought perhaps a new class

```cs
public class ItemNote {
   public int ItemId {get;set;}
   public Item Item {get;set;}

   public Guid UserId {get;set;
   public User User {get;set;}

   public string Note {get;set;}
}
```

```cs
public class Item {
   //snip existing
   public ItemNote Note {get;set;}
}
```

But really that is as far as I have gotten.  If I make that into a property of the `Item` I am not sure how to populate it without iterating the returned UserRooms from the initial query and potentially making thousands of individual extra DB calls or crafting a stored procedure that accepts a bulk UDT and returns the results.

Is there some way to either better structure where the Note goes, or craft a query to include just that user's Note (or null if there is none) that won't turn into a mess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a fully working sample console program, that shows how to setup the model and to run some common queries against it:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace IssueConsoleTemplate
{
    public class User
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Room> Rooms { get; set; } = new HashSet<Room>();
        public ICollection<UserItemNote> UserItemNotes { get; set; } = new HashSet<UserItemNote>();
    }

    public class Room
    {
        public int RoomId { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        public User User { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Box> Boxes { get; set; } = new HashSet<Box>();
    }

    public class Box
    {
        public int BoxId { get; set; }
        public int RoomId { get; set; }

        public Room Room { get; set; }
        public ICollection<BoxItem> BoxItems { get; set; } = new HashSet<BoxItem>();
    }
    
    public class Item
    {
        public int ItemId { get; set; }

        public ICollection<BoxItem> BoxItems { get; set; } = new HashSet<BoxItem>();
        public ICollection<UserItemNote> UserItemNotes { get; set; } = new HashSet<UserItemNote>();
    }

    public class BoxItem
    {
        public int BoxId { get; set; }
        public int ItemId { get; set; }
        
        public Box Box { get; set; }
        public Item Item { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class UserItemNote
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public int ItemId {get;set;}
        public string Note {get;set;}

        public User User {get;set;}
        public Item Item {get;set;}
    }
    
    public class Context : DbContext
    {
        public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Box> Boxes { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<UserItemNote> UserItemNotes { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder
                .UseSqlServer(
                    @"Data Source=.\MSSQL14;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=So63814747")
                .UseLoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.Create(b => b
                    .AddConsole()
                    .AddFilter(level => level >= LogLevel.Information)))
                .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
                .EnableDetailedErrors();
        }

                protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<BoxItem>()
                .HasKey(e => new {e.BoxId, e.ItemId});
            modelBuilder.Entity<UserItemNote>()
                .HasKey(e => new {e.UserId, e.ItemId});
            
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                .HasData(
                    new User {UserId = 1, Name = "John"},
                    new User {UserId = 2, Name = "Hikari"});
            modelBuilder.Entity<Room>()
                .HasData(
                    new Room {RoomId = 11, UserId = 1},
                    new Room {RoomId = 21, UserId = 1},
                    new Room {RoomId = 32, UserId = 2});
            modelBuilder.Entity<Box>()
                .HasData(
                    new Box {BoxId = 111, RoomId = 11},
                    new Box {BoxId = 221, RoomId = 21},
                    new Box {BoxId = 332, RoomId = 32});
            modelBuilder.Entity<Item>()
                .HasData(
                    new Item {ItemId = 1111},
                    new Item {ItemId = 2111}, // without note
                    new Item {ItemId = 3221});
            modelBuilder.Entity<BoxItem>()
                .HasData(
                    new BoxItem {ItemId = 1111, BoxId = 111},
                    new BoxItem {ItemId = 2111, BoxId = 111},
                    new BoxItem {ItemId = 3221, BoxId = 221});
            modelBuilder.Entity<UserItemNote>()
                .HasData(
                    new UserItemNote {ItemId = 1111, UserId = 1, Note = "Great item!"},
                    new UserItemNote {ItemId = 3221, UserId = 2, Note = "I claim this item for myself!"});
        }
    }

    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            using var context = new Context();

            context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
            context.Database.EnsureCreated();

            var allUserNotes = context.UserItemNotes.ToList();

            Debug.Assert(allUserNotes.Count == 2);

            var johnsNotes = context.UserItemNotes
                .Where(n => n.User.Name == "John")
                .ToList();
            
            Debug.Assert(johnsNotes.Count == 1);

            var johnsNotesWithFullModel = context.UserItemNotes
                .Include(n => n.User)
                .ThenInclude(u => u.Rooms)
                .ThenInclude(r => r.Boxes)
                .ThenInclude(b => b.BoxItems)
                .ThenInclude(bi => bi.Item)
                .Where(n => n.User.Name == "John")
                .ToList();

            Debug.Assert(johnsNotesWithFullModel.Count == 1);
            Debug.Assert(johnsNotesWithFullModel[0].User.Rooms.First().Boxes.First().BoxItems.First().Item.ItemId == 1111);
            
            var johnsWithFullModel = context.Users
                .Include(u => u.Rooms)
                .ThenInclude(r => r.Boxes)
                .ThenInclude(b => b.BoxItems)
                .ThenInclude(bi => bi.Item)
                .ThenInclude(i => i.UserItemNotes)
                .Where(u => u.Name == "John")
                .ToList();
            
            Debug.Assert(johnsWithFullModel.Count == 1);
            Debug.Assert(johnsWithFullModel[0].Rooms.First().Boxes.First().BoxItems.Count == 2);
            Debug.Assert(johnsWithFullModel[0].Rooms.First().Boxes.First().BoxItems.First().Item.UserItemNotes.Count == 1);
        }
    }
}
```

To test the code immediately, you can just run this [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bEMzXn).

Comment: Sorry it took a while for me to get some free time to look at this again.  First of all thank you (seriously) for coding an answer.  Your solution however has an issue where if there are no notes for an item, then the item will not be included in the result.  I can come at it from the other direction (from the User down, as I do in the OP) but that gets me ALL usernotes not just the one user's which is ultimately what I am after.  I think EF Core 5 is introducing conditional .Includes so that might be the ultimate solution.

Comment: This should be possible by just arranging the includes in a different order. I changed the script in my answer to have an item without a note as part of the test data and added another query `johnsWithFullModel`, that should accomplish what you want. It also updated the .NET Fiddle accordingly.